# Wear OS, how to get brand/model and os version?

Tags: wear-os

I need to know a little information about the device to ensure to see where things are working and where they are not. Is there any way to return the device brand/model and os version in wear-os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as on any other Android device.

- Brand/model: `Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build.MODEL`
- OS version: `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Comment: How to get 'Wear OS by Google" version like 2.33 ?