# How to get Wear OS version provide by google?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables

I am a android developer and i have devloped a application for wear watch, but i need to find current version of wearOS which are provide by google(Not a Home version) .
How to get programatically wearOS version in in my devlopment code. For better understanding you can see my attechment.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQBRf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6aE5.png)

I am using below code in my devlopement code

```
val info: PackageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
    "com.google.android.wearable.app",
    0
)
return info.versionName
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63985401/1401164

Comment: I need a wear OS version which is provide by google. But it will retun Home version. Please have a look on my attachment.